# Forward traffic to Docker container

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have the following system scenario, where host A (88.12.0.1) and host B (193.11.8.1) are only connected via SSH. On Host B (+172.17.0.2) there is a Docker container running with IP 172.17.0.3.

Now I have an application on host A that has to communicate with an application on Host B (port 22222) and an application on the container (port 22223).

Another application on Host A (port 8081) is running as a server which has to be contacted by the Docker container application.

So far I have managed to forward the traffic only from Host A to B by setting up the following rules on Host A:

```
ssh -NL 22222:193.11.8.1:22222 username@193.11.8.1 -v
ssh -NL 22223:193.11.8.1:22223 username@193.11.8.1 -v
```

Only SSH is available as a port between Host A and Host B.

The first of the above rules works as it is, since it covers the first case of the application on Host A contacting application on Host B.
The second rule is to forward the traffic that is meant for the docker container from Host A to Host B (but would need to be forwarded from there to the docker container).

The mapping on host B, should be that the incoming traffic that has destination port 22223 should be forwarded to the Docker container (172.17.03:22223). The Docker container when sending traffic to 8081 the traffic has to be forwarded to Host A at port 8081, through the Host B were
the container is running on, the SSH channel that connects Host A and B to the server application running on Host A and port 8081.

Comment: what do you mean be only connected via `ssh`, only `ssh` port is open ? or what ?

Comment: Yes only the SSH port is available

Comment: and you want to use `ssh` port to mapping between two different apps on the source and tow different apps on the destination ?

Comment: I updated the question hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't exactly understand what you want but i just translate your edit on your question to `iptables` rules.

But first, whay you don't try to map port when running the container:

```
 docker run -d -p 22223:22223 yourimage
```

This well forward every packet come on the host ip on port `22223` to the container.

Using `iptables` on `B host`:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 193.11.8.1 --dport 22223 -j DNAT --to 172.17.0.3:22223
```

The above command will change the destination of the packet that come to `193.11.8.1:22223` to `172.17.0.3:22223`

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -s 172.17.0.3 --dport 8081 -j DNAT --to 88.12.0.1
```

The above command will change the destination of the packet that come from `172.17.0.3` and the destination port is `8081` to `88.12.0.1:8081`

Comment: I have tried the first rule and the traffic is being send to Host B:22223 but not further to the docker container

Comment: You should be aware where this rule is apply in the iptables and if there is some rule prevent the packet from continue it's way, I edited my answer.

Comment: Just by using the port map from the first command when starting docker forwards the packets into the container; the problem still remaining is to send the packets from within the container to the host, because the iptable rules for port 22223 don't seem to work

Comment: @wasp256 use the last rule that i mentioned

Comment: I tried it agaiin now, but I can't even apply it, I get the error `iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.` when executing the command on host B

Comment: @wasp256 sry, there was a typo in the chain name.

Comment: Great everything works now, thx a lot for the help!